# Which rational functions $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow k$ are regular at the point at infinity?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, self-learning

I am trying to solve a problem in § 1.7 of Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry 1":

"Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Which rational functions $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow k$ are regular at the point at infinity? What order of zero do they have there?"

Here's my attempt so far:

Let $u$ be a rational function on $\mathbb{P}^1$ that is regular at the point at infinity $\mathcal{O}:=[1:0]$. I have already proved in another exercise that if $u$ is regular on all of $\mathbb{P}^1$ then it is constant; hence let $u=p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are homogeneous polynomials in $k[X,Y]$ of the same degree $n\geq 1$, say $p = \sum_{i+j = n} a_{i j} X^i Y^j$ and $q = \sum_{i+j = n} b_{i j} X^i Y^j$. Then since $u$ is regular at $\mathcal{O}$, $q(\mathcal{O}) = b_{n0} \neq 0$ and we see $u(\mathcal{O}) = a_{n 0}/b_{n 0}\in k$. From the question it looks like we ought to be able to show $a_{n 0} = 0$, but I don't really know how to proceed from here. One idea I had was to suppose $a_{n 0}\neq 0$ and look at what happens to $u$ on the affine part $\mathbb{A}_y^1 :=\left\{[a:b]\in\mathbb{P}^1 : b\neq 0\right\}$, but I can't seem to get anywhere with this.

Any tips would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required rational functions are the fractions of the form $\varphi(t)=\frac{p(t)}{q(t)}$ with $p(t),q(t)\in k[t] \:(q(t)\neq 0)$ polynomials satisfying $\operatorname {deg}q(t)\geq \operatorname {deg}p(t)$.
The order of the zero at infinity of $\varphi(t)$ is the difference $\operatorname {deg}q(t)-\operatorname {deg}p(t) \in \mathbb N$.
[This is valid for  an arbitrary field $k$, algebraically closed or not.]

Comment: @ A Bit Too Curious: no, any $p(t), q(t)\neq 0$ is allowed. However we can homegenize these polynomials and then write $F(Z,T) =\frac { P( Z,T)}{Q(Z,T)}$ with indeed $P,Q$ homogeneous of the same degree. For example, $\frac {t^3+17t+2}{t^4-1}=\frac {T^3Z+17TZ^3+2Z^4}{T^4-Z^4}$

Answer (score 2):

I assume from the context we are over the field of complex numbers.

A rational function $\frac uv$ with $u,v\in k[X,Y]$ is regular at $[1:0]$ if and only if $v(1,0)\ne 0$. Since we use projective coordinates, this is equivalent to $v(x,0)\ne 0$ for all $x\in k\setminus\{0\}$. This, again, is now equivalent to $v(X,0)\ne 0$ where capital $X$ denotes the actual variable.

Now think of $v(X,Y)$ as a polynomial in $Y$ over $k[X]$.

Does this help?

Comment: This makes sense but I don't see how it classifies the rational function apart from with the condition "$v$ is not divisible by Y when considered as an element of $k[X][Y]$"... Sorry - I'm probably missing something really obvious!!