# Rational functions regular at the point at infinity of $ \mathbb{P}^{1}.$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Which rational functions are regular at the point of infinity of $ \mathbb{P}^{1}?$ Which order of zero do they have there?

This is an exercise in Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry I".

This question has been partially answered here [Which rational functions $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow k$ are regular at the point at infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150573/which-rational-functions-mathbbp1-rightarrow-k-are-regular-at-the-point-at?noredirect=1&lq=1) and here: [Regularity of rational functions at infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917476/regularity-of-rational-functions-at-infinity)

Such a rational function is some $ F(X,Y) = \frac{G(X,Y)}{H(X,Y)} $ where $ G $ and $ H $ are homogeneous equations of equal degree, and $ H(X,Y) \neq 0. $ Can more be said about this? I don't see how we can be more specific.

My understanding is that the order of the zero is the integer $ \text{deg}(H(X,Y))-\text{deg}(G(X,Y)). $

Is this not always equal to zero? What am I missing?

Comment: I believe you are mixing up two possible coordinate systems. With homogeneous coordinates, a rational function is indeed of the form $\frac{G(X,Y)}{H(X,Y)}$ with $G$ and $H$ of the same degree. With inhomogeneous coordinates $z=X/Y$, a rational function is of the form $g(z)/h(z)$ with no restriction on the degree. Only in that case, the order of the zero at infinity is $\deg h(z)-\deg g(z)$. Read carefully the two linked answers. They are very good and not partial at all.

Comment: @Roland Does this mean that the order of the zero at infinity is not defined for homogeneous coordinates, or is it simply that the order is zero then?

Comment: No this means that if you want to compute the order of zero with the formula $\deg h-\deg g$, you will have to transform your expression so that it uses the inhomogeneous coordinates instead.

Comment: Say $\frac{X^2+XY+Y^2}{XY}=\frac{Y^2((\frac{X}{Y})^2+\frac{X}{Y}+1}{Y^2\frac{X}{Y}}=\frac{z^2+z+1}{z}$ and there you have it : it has a pole at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The only rational functions $p(x)/q(x)$ which are regular at the point at infinity of $\mathbb{P}^1$ are the zero rational function, and those non-zero rational functions for which $\deg q \geq \deg p$. Indeed, it is clear that the zero rational funtion is regular everywhere on $\mathbb{P}^1$, including the point at infinity. Now consider any non-zero rational function $p(x)/q(x)$ (in inhomogeneous coordinates). Suppose $p(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_ix^i$ and $q(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^m b_i x^i$. Then we can express the rational function $p(x)/q(x)$ in terms of the homogeneous coordinates $(X:Y)$ as

\begin{equation}
 \frac{u(X,Y)}{v(X,Y)} := \frac{\sum_{i = 0}^n a_iX^iY^{M-i}}{\sum_{i = 0}^m b_iX^iY^{M-i}},
\end{equation}

where $M = \max(n,m)$. Indeed, note that, as defined above, $u$ and $v$ are homogeneous polynomials is $k[X,Y]$ both of degree $M$. Moreover, if we consider a point $(x:1)$ other than the point at infinity at which $q(x) \neq 0$,

\begin{equation}
\frac{u(x,1)}{v(x,1)} = \frac{\sum_{i = 0}^n a_ix^i}{\sum_{i = 0}^m b_ix^i} = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}.
\end{equation}

The rational function $\frac{u(X,Y)}{v(X,Y)}$ is regular at the point at infinity $(1:0)$ if and only if $v(1,0) \neq 0$, which is true if and only if $M = m \iff m \geq n$. The order of zero at the point at infinity is given by $\deg q - \deg p = m - n$.